# Binding different Target on loaded DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, triggers

I am using a DataTemplateSelector to select different UserControls (reference http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector), according the selected path I select the needed UserControl.

The problem is now, when using the WebBrowser Control, I should bind it to ActualHight of MyScrollViewer, but on all others it works with Hight or else the scroll bar is displayed bad. Must come from the WebBrowser control.

How can I switch the Bindings in the ContentControl between Hight/ActualHight depending of the loaded UserControl?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WebTemplate1">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <controls:WebBrowserUserControl SourceHtml="{Binding Converter={StaticResource UriConverter1}}" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ImgTemplate1">
    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RelativeToAbsolutePathConverter1}}"
           Stretch="None" />
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGridHelper">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DockPanel x:Name="MyDockPanel" Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl"
                                Width="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer,
                                                Path=Width/ActualWidth}"
                                Height="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer,
                                                 Path=Height/ActualHight}"
                                Content="{Binding Path=CurrentItem1,
                                                  Mode=OneWay}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" />
            </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplateSelector` by itself cannot affect the other properties of the `ContentControl`, however, you could use a `Converter` to determine the Width\Height based on the same logic used to determine which template to use.  So something like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl"
                Width="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Converter={StaticResource MyWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter="???"}"
                Height="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Converter={StaticResource MyHeightConverter}, ConverterParameter="???"}"
                Content="{Binding Path=CurrentItem1, Mode=OneWay}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" />
```

I put question marks for the `ConverterParameter` because I'm not clear on how you determine which case calls for which Width/Height.  But you can pass in a parameter that will allow you to decide which value to pass back, and based on that decision, the `Converter` can determine whether to get the ActualWidth/ActualHeight or the Width/Height of the `ScrollViewer` that is passed in.

Comment: Width="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Converter={StaticResource TestWidthConverter1}, ConverterParameter=MyScrollViewer} gives me the ScrollViewer in TestWidthConverter : IValueConverter, but how can I find out which DataTemplate was loaded into ContentControl in order to return Width or ActualWidth?

Comment: How are you determining which `DataTemplate` to use in the `DataTemplateSelector`?  Can you not use the same logic to determine which Width/Height to use?  Otherwise perhaps you can pass in the  `ContentTemplate` of the `ContentControl` as the `ConverterParameter`.

Comment: Could make it work, moved the binding to the template which works now. Thx for the help and learned using the parameters in the converter.